# Permission issue with SQL Server backup via Mintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have created a Maintenance Plan to backup user databases nightly to a folder on the hard drive. However, when this plan is executed it fails with an "Access is denied" error.

Here are the details:

1. I created a Maintenance Plan, adding a "Back Up Database Task" task that backs up all user databases.
2. I verified that the plan is set to run as "SQL Server Agent service account"
3. When I go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and view the Properties fo rthe SQL Server Agent under the Log On tab it shows the **NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT** as the account being used for this service.
4. I created a folder on the hard drive to store these backups named **C:\SQLBackups** and gave full control to the **NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT** account
5. I configured the Maintenance Plan in Step 1 to store to **C:\SQLBackups**, creating subfolders for each database.

When I run the Maintenance Plan I get the following error:

> Executing the query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'C:\SQLBackup..." failed with the following error: "xp_create_subdir() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

If I grant Everyone full access to the **C:\SQLBackups** folder then the Maintenance Plan runs without issue.

What accounts must have access to this folder for the backup to work? I presumed I'd only need to grant access to the **NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT** account, but clearly that is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

I needed to give permissions on the folder to the **NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER** account, as well.

Comment: I was able to get backups to work with adding permissions for only this account. I did not need to add any of the other accounts listed in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Yet you can give permission to group "Authenticated Users" - it worked in my case - Windows Server Domain infrastructure

Comment: Evgeny, good suggestion! After many days trying to discover, give permission to group "Authenticated Users", solved my problem!
Great!
Thanks.